# "se ha" (has been) What is the origin of "se" and what is the origin of "ha"?

Tags: voz-pasiva

I came across it in Memrise app and found no more information about it in the app, googled for it some, but found nothing reasuring.

(I had no idea which tag to put.)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why don't you just google "se Spanish" and "ha Spanish"? The *first* hits I got explain it with full details.

Comment: it is the same as asking what is the origen of "has" and what is the origen of "been"

Comment: Yay | I searched SpanishDict.com and googled things like "ser conjugation". You're correct, if I googled that, I probably wouldn't be here.

Comment: DGaelano | I thought se was conjugation of ser, and didn't know which one...

Comment: If you want an explanation it would be better if you provided some context. Where did you encounter "se ha"? What was the rest of the sentence? In Spanish, "se" has like six different meanings, and it's really hard to tell which one it is with so little information.

Comment: I already got an answer. Check Memrise out. I basicly got "se ha - has been" (in the app) without any more information. Later on in the lection it was implemented in "a vuelo se ha restrado" and I get overall meaning but I had no idea what to make of the words individually.

Comment: "A vuelo se ha restrado"? Are you sure? That's not Spanish; you must have written some words wrong there. Btw, note that in the answer provided, "se" isn't a reflexive pronoun, but a passive "se". They are different things.

Comment: I'm sorry I typed a instead of el and restrado instead of retrasado. The sentence goes like this: "El vuelo se ha retrasado". Double checked it this time. Oh... I did not realise that. It seems this is a bit over my head, I'll have to look more into passive se and the reflexive pronouns and this time I found some pages with good explanations, I think. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Now that makes much more sense :) Yeah, "se" is a real pain in the ass for Spanish kids when studying grammar and sentence parsing at school. "Se" in "retrasarse" is pronominal verb marker. That basically means you just need it because the verb requires it, but it has no real meaning. Some other verbs requiring a pronoun that is semantically meaningless are "ir**se**" (to leave), "olvidar**se**" (to forget) or "divertir**se**" (to have fun), among others . Note this pronoun is not always a "se", but it must agree with the subject (me, te, **se**, nos, os). I hope that's been helpful!

Comment: Well, I've got what I came here for, so I guess it's been helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the reflexive passive construction for the perfect tense.

Reflexive passive constructions are widely used in Spanish, but some of them can't be literally translated as they look.

> *It has been told = Se ha dicho*. (<s>*Ha sido dicho*.</s>)

We omit *been = estado, sido* when we want to use the reflexive passive construction.

Note that both options work when dealing with transitive verbs:

> The stadium **has been** built = El estadio **ha sido** construído = El estadio **se ha** construído.

Comment: I unederstand it completely now. Mainly I just needed to hear that se is a reflexive pronoun, that alone clarified a lot of things (I'm about 3 months into learning Spanish). Thanks again.

Comment: @user11736 It's a long way. The pronoun *se* will be with you always in different cases.